# Delegate not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have this code in my viewController:

```
- (GraphModel *)graphModel
{
    if (!graphModel) {
        graphModel = [[GraphModel alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"graphModel = %@", graphModel);
    }
    return graphModel;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.graphView.delegate = [self graphModel];
     NSLog(@"self.graphview.delegate = %@", self.graphView.delegate);
     [self updateUI];
}
```

but the NSLog just says (null) for self.graphview.delegate
even though the NSLog in graphModel says that I successfully created an object. How can this be?

this is the code for the graphViewDelegate

```
@class GraphView;

@protocol GraphViewDelegate
- (double)yValueForGraphView:(GraphView *)requestor atPosition:(int)i withPrecision:(int)precision;
- (double)scaleForGraphView:(GraphView *)requestor;
@end

@interface GraphView : UIView {
    id <GraphViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (assign) id <GraphViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

and then I have `@synthesize delegate` in graphView.m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely guess: graphView is nil. Calling any method on a nil object has no effect and returns nil, and the .delegate is actually a call to the getter or setter as appropriate. I recommend you add:

```
NSLog(@"self.graphview = %@", self.graphView);
```

As a quick verification.

Comment: when does graphview's memory get set up? I thought it was done automatically?

Comment: Instances aren't automatically given to member variables. If your graphView member is an IBOutlet and is wired up to something in Interface Builder then you're right to assume that it should be loaded once you get viewDidLoad. If you're anything like me, you've possibly wired it up in Interface Builder but not saved your XIB, switched back to Xcode and built with an older copy.

Comment: Yes, graphView is an IBOutlet and I just realized I forgot to wire it up in interface builder, lol. Thanks.

Comment: A GraphView instance isn't created automatically.  You need to either allocate and initialise programmatically and then assign the instance to your `graphView` ivar, or add it to a nib, set your ivar to be an `IBOutlet`, and make the connection in Interface Builder.